# Spring Tool Suite - Unable to change my welcome page fron index.html to index.jsp

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I'm just using the guide "Serving Web Content" as a basis for one of my projects. I simply would like to change the welcome page from index.html to index.jsp. That's it. This is my Package Explorer:

[image: Package Explorer]

Moreover, do you think that this Spring guide is a good basis to start a new project (e.g. for the structure of the files)? I'm a novice.

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend to search for Spring Boot and JSP support, you will find plenty of resources and tutorials that explain in depth how to use JSPs in Spring Boot apps.

Comment: @MartinLippert can you advice some step-by-step article or video? I'm a Spring novice. Or maybe if you have a ready-to-go project that I can download and use on STS, so I can analyze a working example :)

Comment: what about this example from Spring Boot itself? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp - again, if you Google for it, you will find that easily